# How to fetch information from a model in a specific date?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a Book model which contains the publish date for each book.what I need is finding those books that their publish date is older than today by 1 month.Is there any way to do it? 
I write the following code but it fetchs all books to me. Is there any method to make my code to fetch books in specific date?

```
List<Book> book = Book.find("order by publishDate desc").fetch();
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you must  provide with some work around.

Comment: I have provided in the comment for @codemwnic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have provided little info, lets assume your Model class is called Reminder.

```
// Get date 1 month ago
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add( Calendar.MONTH ,  -1 );

List<Reminder> list = Reminder.find("lastupdate <= ?", calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: ow sorry, I have Book Model which contain the publish date of each book what i need is find those books that publish date is older than today by 1 month and present it's title...

Comment: List<Book> book = Book.find("order by publishDate desc").fetch();

Comment: I just write the code above which give me all books in a desc order, I do not know how to specific it.

Comment: List<Book> book = Book.find("publishDate <= ? order by publishDate desc", calendar.getTime()).fetch();